# Corrupt pack file on git aws.push

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, virtualenv, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Upon trying to deploy a new version of application code (Django application) to AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment, I'm encountering the following error:

```
git aws.push
Counting objects: 1648, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (970/970), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1505/1505), 336.19 KiB, done.
Total 1505 (delta 989), reused 645 (delta 436)
remote: 
remote: error: Encountered corrupt pack file: Git command exited with status code 128: error: Trying to write ref refs/heads/master with nonexistent object 8fce6c2b73f03ac271173f85026b3566ef304313
remote: fatal: Cannot update the ref 'refs/heads/master'.
remote: 
remote: 
To https://xxx:xxx@git.elasticbeanstalk.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/repos/xxx/environment-master
! [remote rejected] HEAD -> master (hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://xxx:xxx@git.elasticbeanstalk.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/repos/xxx/environment-master'
```

Nothing seems to have changed on my side. Nothing seemingly changed on AWS's side as well. Deployments worked peachy couple of days ago, but not now.

Any ideas would be very appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit:** here are the deployment snapshot logs showing a myriad of possibly virtualenv related issues: http://pastebin.com/Ec0jHt0i

Comment: have you tried repacking or gcing locally?

Comment: Yup, after seeing pack files mentioned that was the first thing I did, but it didn't seem to have an effect.

Answer (score 0):

Could be because you have exceeded the maximum allowed number of versions (500).

Command to check the number of versions deployed:

```
elastic-beanstalk-describe-application-versions |grep '| git-'|wc -l
```

If the number of versions is exceeded, you can either ask Amazon Web Services team to increase limits for your application, or just delete obsolete versions.

Hope it helps.